# TestNg validation on xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, testng

`.//*[contains(@class, 'alert alert-warning fade in')]`!!  is an xpath which appears on clicking a button when there is 4 times data entry if not it will not display.

When I am try using normal if else condition it is working fine. 
But how to validate in TestNg Assertion case ..?
I am looking for , If that xpath is present exit else continue the method. 
As If else writing is not correct procedure i am trying the below one

```java
public void DataVal() throws InterruptedException {
    click3.click();  //Here click3 is submit button xpath
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Assert.assertFalse(wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(@class, 'alert alert-warning fade in')]")).isDisplayed());
}
```

But getting

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[contains(@class, 'alert alert-warning fade in')]"}
```

Is their anyother way to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it

```java
public void dataVal() {
    String xpath = ".//*[contains(@class, 'alert alert-warning fade in')]";
    List<WebElement> webElements = wd.findElements(By.xpath(xpath));
    if (webElements.isEmpty()) {
        //Add logic to deal with situations wherein the element is not found.
    } else {
        //Element was found.
        Assert.assertTrue(webElements.size() == 1);
        Assert.assertFalse(webElements.get(0).isDisplayed());
    }
}
```